# Merge [onedrive-api] into [onedrive]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Is there any reason to have a separate tag for [onedrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedrive)'s api? I say we merge [onedrive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedrive-api) into [onedrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedrive).

Comment: Because people ask questions about onedrive, where the only on topic questions are about the api... Like this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/35974917/792066

Comment: [onedrive] to rule them all... *my precioussss*

Comment: @Braiam So, we have [onedrive-api] so that we can simply nuke all questions tagged [onedrive]? That does not quite ring true...

Comment: @Deduplicator no, but we close all off topic onedrive questions and leave the onedrive-api questions with their correct tag

Comment: I would suggest the reverse: merge onedrive into onedrive-api

Comment: What about [dropbox] and [dropbox-api]? I'm sure there are others. Don't merge. One is about the service and the other is about the API.

Comment: @rmaddy what would be an on topic question for the service?

Comment: @DanielA.White There are over 2400 questions tag with [dropbox]. I doubt they are all off topic and I doubt they should all be tagged [dropbox-api].

Comment: @rmaddy We got that you think there are such questions. But name some.

Comment: @Deduplicator The first one shown seems OK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985167/determining-the-dropbox-path-in-r

Comment: A plausibly on-topic question could be related to how [tag:win32] file APIs interact with the auto-synchronized `%userprofile%`\ [tag:onedrive] folder on users' machines.

Comment: The real question is: why do you think they should be merged?

Answer (score 2):

I was going to post this as a comment, but... well... it would have been a lot of comments.

On the topic of API tags, there is definitely a precedence for them:

[23andme-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/23andme-api), [2d-context-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2d-context-api), [accessibility-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accessibility-api), [activation-context-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activation-context-api), [ads-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ads-api), [adsense-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adsense-api), [amazon-product-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-product-api), [android-cast-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-cast-api), [android-developer-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-developer-api), [android-embedded-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-embedded-api), [android-fingerprint-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fingerprint-api), [android-host-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-host-api), [android-pdf-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-pdf-api), [android-speech-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-speech-api), [android-wear-data-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-wear-data-api), [android-youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-youtube-api), [ansible-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible-api), [apache-fluent-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-fluent-api), [arcgis-js-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-js-api), [as3-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/as3-api), [asana-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asana-api), [asp.net-web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api), [attach-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attach-api), [azure-ad-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-ad-graph-api), [azure-billing-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-billing-api), [azure-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-graph-api), [azure-management-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-management-api), [battlenet-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/battlenet-api), [behance-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/behance-api), [best-buy-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/best-buy-api), [bing-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bing-api), [bing-maps-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bing-maps-api), [bing-traffic-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bing-traffic-api), [bing-translator-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bing-translator-api), [bitbucket-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitbucket-api), [box-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box-api), [box-view-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box-view-api), [browser-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser-api), [camera-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/camera-api), [c-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-api), [channel-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/channel-api), [cities-skylines-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cities-skylines-api), [compojure-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compojure-api), [confluence-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/confluence-rest-api), [core-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-api), [cosign-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cosign-api), [couchbase-java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchbase-java-api), [coursera-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coursera-api), [criteria-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/criteria-api), [customer-account-data-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customer-account-data-api), [dailymotion-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dailymotion-api), [delicious-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delicious-api), [deviantart-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deviantart-api), [dingo-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dingo-api), [discogs-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discogs-api), [docker-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-api), [dolby-audio-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dolby-audio-api), [dropbox-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropbox-api), [drupal-db-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-db-api), [drupal-field-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-field-api), [drupal-file-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-file-api), [duckduckgo-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duckduckgo-api), [ebay-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-api), [eclipse-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-api), [ef-fluent-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-fluent-api), [elasticsearch-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-api), [elasticsearch-java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-java-api), [etrade-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etrade-api), [ews-managed-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ews-managed-api), [execution-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution-api), [facebook-actionscript-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-actionscript-api), [facebook-ads-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-ads-api), [facebook-as3-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-as3-api), [facebook-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api), [facebook-java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-java-api), [facebook-marketing-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-marketing-api), [facebook-public-feed-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-public-feed-api), [facebook-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-rest-api), [fetch-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fetch-api), [firefox-browser-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-browser-api), [flash-javascript-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-javascript-api), [flickr-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flickr-api), [fogbugz-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fogbugz-api), [form-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-api), [freelancer.com-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freelancer.com-api), [freshbooks-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freshbooks-api), [gamepad-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gamepad-api), [gdata-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdata-api), [ghc-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghc-api), [github-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-api), [gmail-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail-api), [google-admin-audit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-admin-audit-api), [google-admin-settings-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-admin-settings-api), [google-ajax-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-ajax-api), [google-ajax-search-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-ajax-search-api), [google-analytics-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-api), [google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api), [google-assist-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-assist-api), [google-content-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-content-api), [google-data-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-data-api), [google-directory-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-directory-api), [google-distancematrix-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-distancematrix-api), [google-docs-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-docs-api), [google-domain-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-domain-api), [google-drive-android-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-android-api), [google-drive-realtime-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-realtime-api), [google-elevation-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-elevation-api), [google-email-audit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-email-audit-api), [google-email-settings-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-email-settings-api), [google-feed-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-feed-api), [google-finance-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-finance-api), [google-font-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-font-api), [google-geocoding-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-geocoding-api), [google-groups-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-groups-api), [google-language-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-language-api), [google-mirror-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-mirror-api), [google-places-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-places-api), [google-play-developer-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play-developer-api), [google-profiles-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-profiles-api), [google-provisioning-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-provisioning-api), [google-qpx-express-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-qpx-express-api), [google-realtime-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-realtime-api), [google-reporting-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-reporting-api), [google-reseller-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-reseller-api), [google-roads-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-roads-api), [google-search-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-search-api), [google-shopping-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-shopping-api), [google-speech-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-speech-api), [google-spreadsheet-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet-api), [google-tasks-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-tasks-api), [google-weather-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-weather-api), [gradle-tooling-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradle-tooling-api), [grape-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grape-api), [groupon-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groupon-api), [hangouts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hangouts-api), [here-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/here-api), [heroku-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heroku-api), [hubic-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hubic-api), [hudson-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hudson-api), [icloud-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/icloud-api), [instagram-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram-api), [invocation-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invocation-api), [itunes-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itunes-api), [itunes-search-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itunes-search-api), [jaunt-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaunt-api), [java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-api), [java-attach-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-attach-api), [java-collections-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-collections-api), [java-communication-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-communication-api), [java-compiler-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-compiler-api), [java-persistence-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-persistence-api), [javascript-audio-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-audio-api), [jdk-internal-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdk-internal-api), [jira-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira-rest-api), [jira-rest-java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira-rest-java-api), [json-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-api), [kafka-consumer-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kafka-consumer-api), [kafka-producer-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kafka-producer-api), [lending-club-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lending-club-api), [licensecloud-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licensecloud-api), [line-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/line-api), [linkedin-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin-api), [llvm-c++-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llvm-c%2b%2b-api), [low-level-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/low-level-api), [lua-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua-api), [magnification-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magnification-api), [maya-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maya-api), [mediarecorder-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediarecorder-api), [mediawiki-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki-api), [mercurial-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercurial-api), [microsoft-speech-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-speech-api), [mobile-broadband-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-broadband-api), [moodle-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moodle-api), [msbuild-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msbuild-api), [navigation-timing-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigation-timing-api), [neo4j-java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neo4j-java-api), [nest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nest-api), [netbanx-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netbanx-api), [netdna-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netdna-api), [nikeplus-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nikeplus-api), [npr-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npr-api), [nt-native-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nt-native-api), [okta-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/okta-api), [onedrive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedrive-api), [onenote-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onenote-api), [ons-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ons-api), [open-mobile-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-mobile-api), [openoffice-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openoffice-api), [openstack-python-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openstack-python-api), [orange-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orange-api), [overpass-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overpass-api), [owl-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/owl-api), [pipedrive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipedrive-api), [popfax-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popfax-api), [posix-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/posix-api), [print-spooler-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/print-spooler-api), [push-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push-api), [python-c-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-c-api), [python-db-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-db-api), [query-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-api), [rails-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails-api), [realex-payments-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/realex-payments-api), [realtime-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/realtime-api), [reddit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reddit-api), [redmine-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redmine-api), [resource-timing-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resource-timing-api), [revit-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revit-api), [riot-games-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/riot-games-api), [search-engine-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/search-engine-api), [selectors-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selectors-api), [sfdc-metadata-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sfdc-metadata-api), [sharepoint-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-api), [simple-push-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simple-push-api), [slack-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slack-api), [smartsheet-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartsheet-api), [sony-camera-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-camera-api), [sony-lifelog-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-lifelog-api), [sphero-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sphero-api), [stackexchange-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange-api), [steam-web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/steam-web-api), [steamworks-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/steamworks-api), [svn-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn-api), [tcl-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcl-api), [telephone-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/telephone-api), [themoviedb-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/themoviedb-api), [tin-can-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tin-can-api), [twitter-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-rest-api), [twitter-streaming-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-streaming-api), [uber-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uber-api), [ups-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ups-api), [vcloud-director-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcloud-director-rest-api), [vimeo-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vimeo-api), [vso-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vso-rest-api), [watch-face-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watch-face-api), [wc-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wc-api), [wcf-web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcf-web-api), [weather-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weather-api), [web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-api), [web-audio-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-audio-api), [webfm-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webfm-api), [webspeech-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webspeech-api), [wide-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wide-api), [wikidata-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wikidata-api), [wikipedia-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wikipedia-api), [wildfire-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wildfire-api), [windows-firewall-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-firewall-api), [wordpress-json-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-json-api), [wordpress-rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-rest-api), [workfront-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workfront-api), [wp-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wp-api), [xero-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xero-api), [xpath-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath-api), [yahoo-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-api), [yahoo-boss-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-boss-api), [yahoo-weather-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-weather-api), [yandex-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-api), [youtrack-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtrack-api), [youtube.net-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube.net-api), [youtube-analytics-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-analytics-api), [youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api), [youtube-data-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api), [youtube-iframe-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-iframe-api), [youtube-javascript-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-javascript-api), [youtube-livestreaming-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-livestreaming-api), [youtube-v3-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-v3-api), [zomato-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zomato-api)

I'm sure that a large number of these tags also have a service tag which excludes the `-api`, so unless you're going to start a campaign against API tags, I think this request is a non-starter.

You *could* make a case to clean up the [onedrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedrive) tag, which is probably necessary given the inherently off-topic nature of the tag itself (though there is a possibility that it may receive valid on-topic questions that don't have anything to do with the API); but no, I see no convincing reason to merge these tags.

A better question than the one you asked would be "Is there any reason ***not*** to have a separate tag for onedrive's api?", or "Is there any reason to merge onedrive's api tag with its service tag?"