# Merge [box] and [box-api]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Related: [Merge [onedrive-api] into [onedrive]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318958/merge-onedrive-api-into-onedrive)

I propose we merge [box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box) into [box-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box-api) to avoid ambiguity of [box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box).