# The [box] is overflowing

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The tag [box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box) seems to be in a sorry state at the moment. With currently 794 questions, the tag information used to refer to the Box cloud content management service:

> Box Inc. is an online file sharing and cloud content management service for businesses. The company adopted a freemium business model, and provides up to 50 GB of free storage for personal accounts.

However, it has been substantially used for questions involving other kinds of "box"es. As a consequence, the info was edited to the following:

> Avoid using this tag. It has multiple unrelated meanings and therefore could be confusing.

Moreover, questions about the use of the company's Box API could be tagged with [box-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box-api) instead. A synonym between [box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box) [box-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box-api) has been proposed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368052/merge-box-and-box-api), but this would bring more harm than good, considering the amount of mistagged questions that would bring and the [potential reluctance to merge tags with their respective `-api` counterpart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319067/1233251).

It might be worth proceeding with the burnination process, considering its level of ambiguity.

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The previous description only matched the contents of the question when it's about the Box API. Right now, the tag adds very little to the question, even suggesting that it should not be used.

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

"box" is not a concept specifically about programming. Other meanings employed in existing questions may relate to programming in some way.

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

The information it adds is often redundant. For the case of questions about the Box API, [box-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box-api) is sufficient. Before the tag information edit, it could also be misleading.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

There are multiple disparate meanings:

- The Box file storage and sharing company, which provides a programmatic interface. They could just be retagged to [box-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box-api). Occasionally, the tag is present to mean a Box integration with SharePoint. From the many questions I checked, any other use of the tag is likely to be off-topic.
- Drawing boxes in a console or another canvas (including technologies as distinct as matplotlib and CSS).
- Box components in HTML or other GUI frameworks such as .NET (e.g. dialog box, text box, radio box, check box, etc.)
- In Rust, it has been used at least twice to refer to `Box<T>`, a standard generic type for uniquely owned heap-allocated values.

> 5. Is it effectively harmful?

Well, the quality of questions with this tag seems subpar on average, although that can be said about questions in many other tags. It does not seem to attract blatant trash fire, despite the relation with Box cloud.

Comment: We certainly should drop [box]

Comment: Yeah, we should think outside the [box]

Comment: Using [box]es to put code in is not very welcoming for the code in question...

Comment: It might also mean *boxes*, a Gnome facility for managing virtual machines.   See https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes

Comment: Does Trogdor [box], or is he into other martial arts instead?

Comment: @EJoshuaS [tag:boxing] is pretty much something else. :)

Comment: @E_net4wisheshappyholidays If we burninate this tag, wouldn't he be UNboxing?

Comment: There is [tag:unbox] too :p